# xterm python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.6, xterm, subprocess

If using subprocess to execute an xterm on linux, which in turn executes some other process, it seems that Python (2.6.5) will never recognize that the process (xterm) has completed execution.

Consider the following code:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('xterm -iconic -title "FOO_BAR" -e sleep 5'))
while True:
    if proc.poll():
        print 'Process completed'
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This will loop infinitely until you terminate the Python interpreter. I'm guessing that this is probably caused by some oddity with xterm, and not a direct cause of the Python subprocess module, but maybe there are some other smart people out there that could shed some light on the situation.

Note: Calling `proc.communicate()` will in fact return when the xterm completes, but for some reason the poll method will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program doesn't distinguish between `proc.poll()` returning `None` (meaning that the process is still running) and `proc.poll()` returning `0` (meaning that the process terminated with an exit value of zero, conventionally indicating successful completion).  Change this line:

```
if proc.poll():
```

to this:

```
if proc.poll() is not None:
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: use `is` for singletons such as `None`

Comment: I can't believe that I made this fundamental mistake in usage of the poll function. Thank you for the "smack upside the head" :-)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ha, yes, sorry -- old C habits die hard.  I've updated the answer.